# See more button shifting text when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i click read more the text on the right column shift. i need them to stay as they are. and i need the "show more" button at the bottom left of the list. is there any way we can fix this by just adjusting the code. I am new to javascript so i cant target the problem.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
 #more {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .columns {
      columns: 2;
      -webkit-columns: 2;
      -moz-columns: 2;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .hed {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 800;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 15px 0px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="columns">
      <li class="hed">Elementary</li>
      <li>Maps: Primary: ELS</li>
      <li>Maps: Primary: Readiness</li>
      <li>Maps: Primary: Outline World Map</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Land Use Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Population Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Outline World Map</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 1 Native Americans</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 2 Spanish Explorers</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 3 Explorers</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 4 The Great Exchange</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 5 European Settlements</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 6 Thirteen British Colonies</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 7 Slavery in the Americas</li>
      <li>U.S. History: 8 Revolutionary War</li>
      <li>State Map</li>
      <li class="hed">Secondary</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Physical</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Political</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Continents and Oceans Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Wealth of Countries Thematic</li>
      <li>Maps: Intermediate: Precipitation Thematic</li><span id="dots">... 
    </span>
      <span id="more">
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Temperature Thematic</li>
  <li>Maps: Intermediate: Time Zones Thematic</li>
   <li>State Map</li>
       </span>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This snippet is missing the code for `myFunction`?

Comment: this is the script used for code <script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>

Comment: whats the issue, Can you provide more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your button is not below the lists like you want is because your unordered list `columns` has `float: left`. Perhaps `column-gap` can achieve the look you want.

The reason the list items move around is because your columns are self-balancing. The more items you add at once the greater the shift, and you may notice that if only one item were to replace the ellipsis the columns would stay the same. Maybe you could try `column-fill: auto` ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp